# Is $C\left(1+\cos\left(\pi\frac{\sqrt{\delta_x^2 + \delta_y^2}}{R}\right)\right)^2$ a separable filter kernel?

Tags: kalman-filter

I have a 2D morphology filter with kernel of radius $R$, some scaling constant $C$ and weight function:

$$C\left(1+\cos\left(\pi\frac{\sqrt{\delta_x^2 + \delta_y^2}}{R}\right)\right)^2$$

Where $[\delta_x$,$\delta_y]$ is vector from destination position to source sample for which weight function is defined.

- Is there chance it is separable filter?
- How one can proove it?
- What weight functions would look like for separated x and y filter passes?

Comment: OP here, accordingly to http://www.dspguide.com/ch24/3.htm gaussian filter is the only separable and radially symmetric filter. So as given filter is not gaussian and is radially symmetric I guess it is not separable.